# How to run an EXE file through URL on .Net shared hosting

Tags: javascript, c#, php, .net, shared-hosting

I try to run a simple ETL process on a schedule to populate a SQL Server database table on a .Net shared hosting. The EXE file will be hosted with the website and when it runs it will make some API calls and get data to update the website's SQL table. 
My hosting company allows such thing (to call an exe file on schedule) with an extra fee, but they require me to have it wrapped and be called using URL. They don't mind any technology to use as long as I provide a URL. I did few attempt to get this setup working with no luck. For example I tried two ways below: Note, I just started to learn JavaScript, I use C# but this is my first time attempt to do something like that and I might be completely off. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Open PMETL</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function runProgram()
        {
            try {           
                var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");                 
                var myPMETL="http://trudat.live/RefreshData.exe";
                shell.Run(myPMETL);
                }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }

        }        

        function runProgram02() {           
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    var excelApp = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                    }
                catch (e) {
                alert (e.message);
                }       
            }
                else {
                alert ("Your browser does not support this example.");
                }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <a href="javascript:runProgram()">Run program</a>    
       <a href="javascript:runProgram02()">Run program02</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You understand that javascript runs on the client (i.e. in your browser), right? Both of those are javascript, and both of them will try and run on the client side (assuming the browser you use to access the page has javascript enabled), and probably only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Your hosting company probably wants you to invoke the URL from the server, not from the browser. Invoking http://something.com/foo/bar.exe directly from the client seems like a real bad idea. Have you asked them for an example?

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, I understand that JavaScript will run on the client side, but I don't know how to run a url using server only. I asked for example and they declined, I got answers like this "Sorry, you'll need to develop a url to call the .exe file" "Please note that the task you'd like to run should to be a link. Please provide us here once you've developed it". My original request for them was to run the exe file directly using Windows tasks.

Comment: I think you should write some backend c# code to run the exe file, you can write this code in Page load method so every time url hit it will run the code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve that by adding a new page  to my ASP.NET application and port the console application into the code-behind C# and invoke the code through the Page_Load() method. This allowed my to give the hosting company a URL like http://mydomain/ExePage.aspx without impacting my original application since this new page is not reachable from the application's menu. it was a convenient way to give me what I needed.
I assume this is not a typical solution since I had the advantage to have the source code of the EXE program, but nevertheless it is a very effective, and this might help someone in the future.